# Странные вертикальные полосы во всплывающем окне прогресса знаков за проверку

Tags: дефект, дизайн, очередь-проверок, знаки

Заметил небольшой косяк в оформлении, возможно кто-то уже обращал внимание сообщества на эти проблемы, если нет, то я был рад помочь:

здесь какие-то непонятные полоски, может так и нужно я не знаю :)

Браузер Chrome v.  70.0.3538.77/ OS Windows 10 pro *64. Лично я могу добраться до этого окна когда перехожу в любую из очередей проверок.

> [image: Элемент списка]

Comment: 1. Не воспроизводится, но у меня там другой баг — гражданский долг сильно выпирает за подложку. 2. Уже постили пару раз

Comment: @älёxölüt, обновил вопрос.

Comment: еще раз обновил :)

Comment: [Завёл багу](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/318188/339911) с выходом за границы на MSE.

Comment: не очень понял в чем прикол этих багов, но я так смотрю что этому блоку не везет что-то)

Comment: Прикол багов в том, что на SE обычно кладут болт на неанглоязычый дизайн, но тут даже en-вариант оказался кривой :)

Comment: Про гражданский долг даже я создавал тред на MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314900/260198

Comment: @Suvitruf а я даже там отмечался в комментариях :)